# Apache Beam Pipeline Query Table After Writing Table

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a Apache Beam/Dataflow pipeline that is writing results to a BigQuery table.  I would then like to query this table for a separate portion of the pipeline. However, I can't seem to figure out how to properly set up this pipeline dependency. The new table that I write (and then want to query) is left joined with a separate table for some filtering logic and that is why I actually need to write the table and then run the query. The logic would be as follows:

```
with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
    table_data = p | 'CreatTable' >> # ... logic to generate table ...

    # Write Table to BQ
    table_written = table_data | 'WriteTempTrainDataBQ' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(...)

    query_results = table_written | 'QueryNewTable' >> beam.io.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(query=query_new_table))
```

if `query_new_table` is actually a query of an already existing BQ table and I change to `query_results = p |` instead of `table_written` this works properly. However, if I try to query the table that I am writing in the middle of the pipeline then I cannot get the pipeline step to "wait" until that table has actually been generated. Is there any way to do this that I am overlooking?

When I try to make this step sequential, I am getting an assertion error `assert isinstance(pbegin, pvalue.PBegin) AssertionError` which I am reading to mean that `table_written` is the issue as it is not a valid PCollection instance.

Does anybody know what I would could put in place of table_written to make this actually run sequentially as desired?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The use case "do something after a BigQuery write is complete" is not supported by Beam currently. The only workaround is to run separate pipelines: have your main program be: run the pipeline that writes to BigQuery; wait for the pipeline to finish; run another pipeline that reads from BigQuery.

This is a very frequently requested feature and we're beginning to design this support (more generally, upgrading various IO writes to support sequencing operations after them), but I don't know when we'll be done.

Comment: Very helpful! Just to clarify I'm understanding this correctly, would the best practice currently be a single main program `run()` that has 1) `with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p1:` to write to BQ and then 2) `with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p2:` to read from BQ or are you suggesting within the main program to actually have two separate `run()` functions?

Comment: As far as beam is concerned, it doesn't matter: do whichever seems more readable to you according to your Python style sense :)

Comment: @jkff could you tell us if there are news about this? Is currently possible to query right after write to bigquery with Beam? Thanks!

Comment: There's an in-progress PR https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/6055 but it's not done yet.

Comment: @jkff and what could be done if the pipeline is a streaming pipeline? In this case is not possible to run 2 pipeline in which the second wait for the first to finish, isn't?

Comment: It is, though it is not supported by BigQueryIO yet either, and nobody is working on implementing that yet. Please see the Wait.on() transform - it generalizes the idea of "do A then B" in a way that makes sense even in streaming.

Comment: Is this request still under progress and we have to go through the workaround of writing multiple pipelines?

Comment: To my knowledge, the BigQueryIO side of things hasn't been completed. Consider re-raising this issue on user@beam.apache.org - perhaps someone will pick it up where it left off.