# Unable to execute more than 1 function from main class while triggering dataflow pipeline from cloud function

Tags: python-2.7, function, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

Since I am performing some tasks after WriteToBigQuery operation, I have written two separate functions and executing them in main class to run my dataflow pipeline sequentially. I have created template for the same on cloud storage and trying to trigger this custom pipeline template from cloud function, but it is directly executing second function and not first one at all.

here is my main class:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "Starting Dataflow Pipeline"
    writetobq()
    writetocsv()
```

Some Cloud function code :

```
BODY = {
        "jobName": "{jobname}".format(jobname=JOBNAME),
        "parameters": {
        },
        "environment": {
            "tempLocation": "gs://{bucket}/temp".format(bucket=BUCKET),
            "zone": "europe-west1-b"
        }
    }
request = service.projects().templates().launch(projectId=PROJECT, gcsPath=GCSPATH, body=BODY)
response = request.execute()
```

I dont get any error while triggering this pipeline but it is only executing writetocsv(), I want that first it should execute writetobq() and then writetocsv(). If I run this pipeline code locally then it is giving me expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Dataflow templates (I assume this is what you meant by template) does not execute your main class. It just stores a Dataflow pipeline and executes that pipeline. So if you need to execute the second function as a part of the template, it has to be a part of the pipeline (for example, a ParDo step).

In your case though seems like you need something that follows `WriteToBigQuery'. Unfortunately this is not possible today since`WriteToBigQuery` step does not return a result.

Can you add execute the second function from the code where you launch the template (either as a local execution or a second Dataflow job) ?

Comment: Please try to refer this url: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46992455/apache-beam-pipeline-query-table-after-writing-table

In my dataflow template this is what I am doing same like having 2 separate functions in main class.

Comment: def writetobq():
    table_schema = 'schema'
    JOB_NAME = 'test'
    pipeline_options = {my pipeline options}
    options = PipelineOptions.from_dictionary(pipeline_options)
    interaction_query = """myquery"""
    with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as p:
        rows = p | 'read from BQ' >> beam.io.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(query=interaction_query,use_standard_sql=True))
        final_data = (rows | "Write to BQ" >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(table=processedDetails,schema=table_schema,project=project, dataset=dataset_id,write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND))

Comment: def writetocsv():
 table_schema = 'schema'
    JOB_NAME = 'test'
    pipeline_options = {options}
    options = PipelineOptions.from_dictionary(pipeline_options)
    del_query = """delquery"""
    with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as p:
        delete_rows = p | 'read' >> beam.io.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(query=delete_query,use_standard_sql=True))
        required_data = delete_rows | 'Retriving' >> beam.ParDo(RequiredData())
        data_conversion = required_data | 'Convert' >> beam.ParDo(DictToCSV())
        write_to_csv = data_conversion | "Write" >> beam.io.WriteToText(file)